# Python parallel_bulk, info says no errors, but nothing in index

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Here is the part of my python code. Took me a while to get this working without any errors as I didn't know what was the input structure function was accepting... Anyway here it is:

```
docs = [
           {
            "Created":  "2021-05-30T18:35:16.587Z",
            "Action":  "AccessRequestCancelled",
            "Type":  "ACCESS_REQUESTT",
            "Actor":  "mateparac",
            "Target":  "mateparac",
            "Stack":  "wps",
            "TrackingNumber":  "2c9180867a5ca31f017a5e332e763f9",
            "Objects":  "ACCESS",
            "Operation":  "REQUEST",
            "Status":  "CANCELLED",
            "TechnicalName":  "ACCESS_REQUEST_CANCELLEDs",
            "Name":  "Request Access Cancelled!"
        },
        {
            "Created":  "2021-04-30T18:35:16.587Z",
            "Action":  "AccessRequestCancelled",
            "Type":  "ACCESS_REQUESTT",
            "Actor":  "mateparac",
            "Target":  "mateparac",
            "Stack":  "wps",
            "TrackingNumber":  "2c9180867a5ca31f017a5e332e763f9",
            "Objects":  "ACCESS",
            "Operation":  "REQUEST",
            "Status":  "CANCELLED",
            "TechnicalName":  "ACCESS_REQUEST_CANCELLEDs",
            "Name":  "Request Access Cancelled!"
        },
        {
            "Created":  "2021-04-30T18:35:16.587Z",
            "Action":  "AccessRequestCancelled",
            "Type":  "ACCESS_REQUESTT",
            "Actor":  "mateparac",
            "Target":  "mateparac",
            "Stack":  "wps",
            "TrackingNumber":  "2c9180867a5ca31f017a5e332e763f9",
            "Objects":  "ACCESS",
            "Operation":  "REQUEST",
            "Status":  "CANCELLED",
            "TechnicalName":  "ACCESS_REQUEST_CANCELLEDs",
            "Name":  "Request Access Cancelled!"
        }
]


def insert_data(documents, indexname):
    for document in documents:
        json_line = {}
        for key in document:
            json_line[key] = document[key]
        yield {
            '_op_type': 'index',
            '_index': indexname,
            '_type': 'doc',
            '_source': json.dumps(json_line)
        }


for success, info in parallel_bulk(es, insert_data(docs, "sailpont-dev-logs"), chunk_size=5000, thread_count=4, queue_size=4):
    if not success:
        print('A document failed:', info)
```

During debug, info returns all good, no errors but I am not finding these documents in index. Initially I tried with elasticsearch.helpers.bluk with following code, but got error.

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'action_request_validation_exception', 'Validation Failed: 1: index is missing;2: index is missing;3: index is missing;4: index is missing;5: index is missing;6: index is missing;7: index is missing;8: index is missing;9: index is missing;10: index is missing;11: index is missing;12: index is missing;13: index is missing;14: index is missing;15: index is missing;16: index is missing;17: index is missing;18: index is missing;19: index is missing;20: index is missing;21: index is missing;22: index is missing;23: index is missing;24: index is missing;25: index is missing;26: index is missing;27: index is missing;28: index is missing;29: index is missing;30: index is missing;31: index is missing;32: index is missing;33: index is missing;34: index is missing;35: index is missing;36: index is missing;37: index is missing;38: index is missing;39: index is
```

I assume problem input data, but it's structured as per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/docs-bulk.html#docs-bulk-api-request

```
test_docs = '''
{ "create" : { "_index" : "sailpont-dev-logs", "_type" : "doc"} }
{ "Created":  "2021-04-30T18:35:16.587Z", "Action":  "AccessRequestCancelled","Type":  "ACCESS_REQUESTT","Actor":  "matepric","Target":  "brianschaffner","Stack":  "wps","TrackingNumber":  "2c9180867a5ca31f017a5e332e763f9", "Objects":  "ACCESS", "Operation":  "REQUEST", "Status":  "CANCELLED","TechnicalName":  "ACCESS_REQUEST_CANCELLEDs","Name":  "Request Access Cancelled!"}
{ "create" : { "_index" : "sailpont-dev-logs", "_type" : "doc"} }
{ "Created":  "2021-04-29T18:35:16.587Z", "Action":  "AccessRequestCancelled","Type":  "ACCESS_REQUESTT","Actor":  "matepric","Target":  "brianschaffner","Stack":  "wps","TrackingNumber":  "2c9180867a5ca31f017a5e332e763f9", "Objects":  "ACCESS", "Operation":  "REQUEST", "Status":  "CANCELLED","TechnicalName":  "ACCESS_REQUEST_CANCELLEDs","Name":  "Request Access Cancelled!"}
'''
bulk(es,test_docs, "sailpont-dev-logs")
```

Not sure what is the problem here in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You just have an error in type

`_doc` and not `doc` in `'_type': 'doc',`

And also source should be your `dict` directly helpers will do the job for you so

```py
for document in documents:
    yield {
        '_op_type': 'index',
        '_index': indexname,
        '_type': '_doc',
        '_source': document
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that typo. For source I replaced `json.dumps(json_line)` with `json_line` but still no documents in es. Confusing part is why I am not getting error :(

Comment: first of all, try to index only 1 document to see if there is anythings wrong, and switch to bulk, and like json is not the only problem, doc_type is also wrong, I will suggest also to put named args, since elastic python library had changes args order

Comment: you were right, I can't even document a single document. Funny thing is if I copy/paste same data (single document) to Kibana Console - Dev Tools, document is created and I can find it. `res = es.create(index="sailpont-dev-logs", body=doc, id=1111)` says created but nothing in ES... I will try with downgrading client to <7.0

Comment: Found the problem, typo in my index name!!

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the bulk part

```
t = test_docs.splitlines()
n = list(map(json.loads, filter(lambda x: x, t)))
bulk(es, n, "sailpoint-dev-logs")
```